# Long running VMWare snapshots are bad.... but what about VMDKs on a ZFS\LVM snapshot?

Tags: virtualization, storage, lvm, zfs, snapshot

The [VMWare KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025279) and multiple blogs state that long running snapshots are bad for both performance reasons and integrity.  They have valid points.

Granted this is not with ESXi but rather Workstation\VirtualBox on a *NIX server I do see many blogs touting using LVM (or even ZFS) snapshots.  Assuming LVM they essentially store their VMDKs on an LVM volume and take all the snapshots they want.

I don't see how this solution is practically any different than simply using the VMDK snapshots but VMWare mentions nothing bad about it from a performance or integrity perspective.  A lot of blogs tout this as a snapshoting solution.

With that being said are Long running VMWare snapshots bad if they are not true VMWare snapshots but rather the VMDK on an LVM\ZFS volume?

**Clarification**

A long-running snapshot is a snapshot that runs for a long time, even continuously.  Let's assume I set up a few Windows VMs, snapshot them at the LVM level, and run them for a few weeks or months (perhaps even shapshotting throughout).  When I want to roll back I simply roll back the snapshot to return to a previous version.

The VMWare KB specifically states (for native VMWare snapshots)

"Use no single snapshot for more than 24-72 hours. Snapshots should not be maintained over long periods of time for application or Virtual Machine version control purposes."

As we all know people run LVM\ZFS snapshots for enormous amounts of time with no ill effects.

Comment: It depends. Can you give more information about what you're trying to do? What is a "long-running snapshot" in your opinion?

Comment: @ewwhite Clarified

Comment: Why do you want to "roll them back"? You're very focused on wanting to do that. Being more specific on your reasoning can help see if there's a better solution to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want the ability to spin up various VMs and every few weeks simplky roll them back to their nice clean state.  I could always re-deploy OVAs but that means I have to keep large OVAs.  Snapshots seems like the right tool for the job

Comment: Snapshots at the storage level are not the right solution for this. What version and license level of VMware are you using?

Comment: Nothing is licensed yet.  I am just pondering options.  Everything would be the latest.  We are very cheap and not looking to use a bunch of licensed solutions.  VMWare & Virtualbox both support snapshots at the VMDK level hopwever as I pointed out VMWare frowns upon this.  A lot of blogs mention doing it at the filesystem level

Comment: possible duplicate of [VMWare: Are long running snapshots really THAT bad?](http://serverfault.com/questions/642332/vmware-are-long-running-snapshots-really-that-bad)

Comment: VM_Storage_inception - @ewwhite has provided more or less the correct answer based on info provided.  Basically you just have some bad assumptions going in regarding what snapshots are for.  :) 

The gist of it, is regardless of virtualization solution (VMWare, KVM, Virtualbox, Xen) - create your "gold" template (thin provision to save on space) and then deploy your new VM(s) off of it.  Snapshotting is for point in time rollbacks to real live data.  Also keep in mind, you CAN'T EVER snapshot an AD Domain Controller, or any other clustered servers.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't focus on snapshots](https://serverfault.com/questions/642332/vmware-are-long-running-snapshots-really-that-bad). It's clouding your judgment :)

VMware has [templating and cloning functionality](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50/GUID-F40130B0-0194-4A41-91FA-1A967721924B.html) built into vCenter. You need a $600 vSphere Essentials license to enable this.

You can create a VM to your taste, then clone it to a template. That template can then be used to [generate new virtual machines](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50/GUID-9062F225-E01B-42BA-8AFB-8EA4069068FE.html).

This allows you to have a "clean state" but also create long-running or permanent VMs from that master image. No snapshots needed.

Comment: The problem with templates is you have to store a large OVA file for the template.  Plus you have to redeploy the template.  With snapshots it's a simple rollback.  What are the issues with snapshots?

Comment: I've given you the steps to do this the right way, as sanctioned by vmware. You don't have to listen or heed the advice...

Comment: Also, I said nothing about OVA templates. Please read the linked documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the root of this question is that there are two fundamentally different methods of doing snapshots.

**A VMWare snapshot** means that is halts writes to its primary disk and instead puts all writes into a separate snapshot disk. Reverting to this snapshot means discarding all the writes since it was taken (which causes very little overhead), however deleting it means applying the separated writes to the primary disk. This can be IO intensive, and can cause storage congestion because there's no way I know of to make this traffic have a lower priority than regular IO.

**A storage snapshot** can be done many ways, but none of them are like the above VMWare snapshot. They all have some sort of tradeoff, but none of them require a mass of updates to be sent as unprioritizable host IO to a storage device. Some examples of storage snapshots are copy-on-write, copy-after-write, and Netapp-style write anywhere snapshots.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  In your opinion would Storage based snapshots cause an issue with VMDKs being stored on them?

Comment: Assuming block based storage (iSCSI or FC LUNs), then snapshots are on the hardware and don't care whether the ones and zeros you write are a VMDK or a boot sector. If it's NFS, then snapshots will likely be more granular.

The issues about snapshots depend on the method being considered. Copy-on-write snaps on a LUN, for example, will begin to degrade performance if you have too many snapshots, but not based on how long you keep them.

Comment: @VM_Storage_Inception But if VMware isn't aware of the storage and the snapshotting technology, then yes, there's a problem. You'll have duplicate virtual machine IDs, and complications with registering the virtual machines with the ESXi host. Please try to understand the advice I'm giving you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ZFS snapshoting works well for that, with no performance penalty for adding them as you please. (also easy to replicate for backup, etc)

However there isn't any coordination with vmware though so you do need to remove and re-add them to the inventory manually when you revert snapshots. Whether it is a particularly good solution for you depends very much on your workflow.

Also with any major time difference there are the usual restore issues with time syncing/domain auth, etc.

Comment: I was thinking of ZFS (allocating a large chunk of my VMFS datastore to a vSAN running ZFS), however doesn't ZFS require a lot of RAM\CPU?  I'de rather not waste those resources on a vSAN.  That's a good suggestion though.

Comment: It is kind of a given that you can't have a storage solution without using the resource of a storage solution.

Comment: Heh I understand.  The DAS for example is low overhead as far as CPU\Memory are concerned because it is DAS on a RAID card.  Unfortunately VMWare snapshots suck!!